# Кнопка удаления только для авторов комментариев

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Я разрабатываю [приложение](https://sportpredictions.firebaseapp.com/#/) (прогнозы на теннисные матчи)

Последний штрих перед запуском проекта, это я хочу добавить кнопку "удалить комментарий".

Кнопка в HTML выглядит так:

```
<button ng-show="" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove marginio"></button>
```

Пример комментария с кнопкой вы можете увидеть перейдя по ссылке и выбрав прогноз "Nadal R. / Verdasco F. vs Bolelli S. / Seppi A." (или же сами быстренько зарегистрироваться и пописать комменты где угодно).

Я пользуюсь субд Firebase, и получается, что у каждого прогноза (predictionId) свои комментарии. И мне надо сделать так, чтобы кнопка была видна только юзеру который добавил это коммент. Вот тут я и застрял.

Вот мой код: https://github.com/NiR-IT/tennispredictions

service под комменты - scripts/services/comments.js
controller - scripts/controllers/browse.js

Comment: добавляйте необходимый код **непосредственно** в вопрос. Ссылки могут быть лишь дополнением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике, у тебя при авторизации пользователя в `$rootScope` должна быть идентификация пользователя (его `Id`, `userName` ... `someInfo`). При выводе комментариев, каждый коммент будет иметь идентификатор создавшего его, например 5. Ты в контроллере (для простоты) можешь определить в `$scope.authUserId = $rootScrope.User.getId()` - это к примеру, вернет идентификатор текущего авторизованного пользователя. а на кнопке будешь брать (если у тебя `ng-repeat="comment in comments"`) comment.userId и дописывать в директиву `ng-show`.

Получится примерно такое:

```
<button 
   ng-show="authUserId == comment.userId" 
   ng-click="deleteComment(comment)" 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove marginio">
</button>
```